# Icon library for UI Design

Tags: website-design, design, icons, ux-designer

I am starting the UI design for a large scale project for which I need a good library of icons.

Looking for suggestions on good icon packs (free/paid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending by your kind of project and the brand you are designing, here there are some:

- Ionicons (Free) https://ionicons.com/
- Font Awesome (Both free and paid version) https://fontawesome.com/
- Material Icons (Free) https://material.io/resources/icons/
- Feather (Free) https://feathericons.com/
- Open Iconic (Free) https://useiconic.com/open
- Streamline icons (Paid) https://streamlineicons.com/

Answer (score 0):

IBM Design Language.
It has some interesting icons for data.
https://www.ibm.com/design/language/iconography/ui-icons/library/